# Android Studio freezes when performs git merge

Tags: android, git, android-studio, git-merge

I'm using Android Studio version 1.5 on my MacBook Air 13" (8 GB RAM). I'm using built-in Git feature for my project's version control. I try merge local and remote branches which contains conflicts and when I solve them and click Apply button Android Studio just freezes and I can't do anything! I've tried wait for 5 and more minutes but there's no changes: Android Studio stays freeze. However, other programs on my Mac are working good! At screen you can see what I have as a result. How can I avoid freeze? Thanks for helping
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. It just seems there is an invisible dialog that takes the focus. Try pressing **esc** or **enter** button and then see if you can do anything.